# What does schematic of a transceiver equalizer and transceiver preemphasis circuit look like

Tags: transceiver

I have been reading about transceiver basics and was wondering about how 3 circuits look like:

1. Receiver equalizer.
2. Transmitter preemphasis.
3. Clock data recovery.

Where can I find a circuit diagram and detailed explaination of their working, more like a "white paper".

Comment: Are you asking about radio or optical transceivers?

Comment: Lets take a case, I am asking this question because of these things being in Altera FPGAs. They are used with Ethernet and PCIe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this part from Texas Instrument, used for pre-emphasis and receiver equalization of LVDS signals.[DS25BR100](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds25br100.pdf)

Comment: actually I wanted to look at the actual circuit that carries out such an enigmatic task.